# Copying a months FullCalendar events to next month

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar and it works perfect(ish) :)

Now my users are demanding a simple way to copy a full months of scheduled shifts to the next month - or any month.

I already have a "Copy week" function in place and it works fine. But I simply can't figure out the correct way to copy an entire months shifts.
I was thinking to copy "day N Month A" to "day N Month B" but this leads to failure - as the 1. day in the month is constantly moving.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Edit:

The task I'm looking for input on, is really in the PHP/MySQL backend. In the frontend the user simply have 2 selects: Copy month  to  and a button "Copy".

In the backend I receive "mthfrom=>2014-1" and "mthto=>2015-1". I have no problem finding all events from 2014-1 with `SELECT * from dbevent WHERE year(shiftstart)='2014' and MONTH(shiftstart)='1';`.

The problem is that I need to "match" the correct workingdays, so the corresponding weekdays match up in the month copied to. E.g. I want to copy all shifts from January 2014 to March 2014.

- How to make sure that the monday shifts ends up on the correct weekday?
- How to make sure that no shifts end up on saturday/sunday?
- What to do if a user wants to copy a month with 28 days to a month with 31 days or vice/versa?

Comment: After reviewing my question, I can see that I have in no way been clear enough, I'm sorry about that!

Comment: The issue is not the UI - making the user choose the period. But more on how to do the MySQL/PHP code that would copy one month's events to the next month eg.
I can't just do strtotime("$date +1 month) because for example, wednesday October 1. +1 month ends up as saturday November 1.
The webapp is used to plan volunteershifts - so copying as simple as +1 month just don't cut it.
Any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want something like "copy all events from the 29th of September to the 31th of October and insert them beggining at the 3rd of November", is that it ? I understand the issue you have with copying the month as is, i'm just not clear of what you want to achieve.

Comment: You're free to [edit] and improve the question whenever needed. There's a very interesting answer down here, but anyway would be nice to see how you're copying the weeks.

Comment: To clarify, given that on January 2014 the first day is a Wednesday and the first week day is a Monday, what do you want to do? That is, you want the events from 1st January 2014 to go to the 3rd March 2014 (Monday)? Or do you want the event on the first Wednesday (5 March 2014)?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use two datepickers connected (that is, the earliest date of the second should be latter than the date of the first), and use a button to copy the events.

IMO the best way is to copy the events in the server. Assuming you have a DB, you would select the events from the given period and duplicate the events on click of a button.

This way, you will have a "Copy events by period" instead of "copy events by week (and month, and quarter, ..)".

So, your front-end code would be something like this:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='dtpFrom'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class='input-group date' id='dtpTo'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<button id="copyEvents" class="btn btn-default">Copy Events </button>
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script>
$('#dtpFrom').datetimepicker();
$('#dtpTo').datetimepicker();

$("#copyEvents").on('click', function() {
    var dateFrom = $('#dtpFrom').data("DateTimePicker").getDate(),
        dateTo = $("#dtpTo").data("DateTimePicker").getDate();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url-for-server',
        data: {from: dateFrom, to: dateTo},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            // reload events if you want
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
        }
    });
});

// start fullcalendar
$("#calendar").fullCalendar();
</script>
```

The full code is [**in this JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/td7qk5yu/1/) and serves as a demonstration to guide you. I've used Bootstrap, but you can use the datepickers from jQuery UI.

The only thing not present is the server code, that you need to create for yourself. However, you will have the period to copy to the next month, so its just a matter of duplicate the DB rows adding 1 month to each start / end.